# npm skript dont find node

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables

Sorry for the German question before.
I have the following problem. I search about it in the internet but i did't was successfull.

I wanna run my node script with my npm-dev script.
[image: package.json Datei mit dev-script]

I execute " npm run dev". Normal like everytime.

Than i got this error message:
[image: Terminal Fehlermeldung]
It means that node cannot be found.

[image: complete log]

I can execute via the Terminal my JS-File with "node index". Just all my npm-scrips doesn't work.

I think that i have some problems with the environment variables. But if I execute " node -v" or "npm -v" everything work fine.

In my PATH i have " C:\Program Files\nodejs" Not sure if that is all what I need?

Thanks in advance if someone can help me with this Problem.

AD

Comment: Could you ask a question in English?

Comment: können sie dies englische übersetzen und protokoldatei einschliessen?

Comment: @speciesUnknown Correct German in this context: Können Sie Ihre Frage ins Englische übersetzen und die Meldung als Text und nicht als Bild zur Frage hinzufügen?

Comment: @NiklasE. Thanks, but I was just asking the OP to translate into english ( and include the log file but i decided to use one message)

Comment: I know, but this sounds like google translate doing things to literal. Your message is very confusing if you don't know the Engish background.  "protokoldatei einschliessen" means "lock away protocol file".

Comment: Busted @NiklasE.

Comment: i had translate it. Sorry for the german

Comment: but how can i reopen the post?

Comment: I flagged it and said that it was ready to be reopened. I don't know if this will work.